# requesting a route on google maps returns 404 page

Tags: wpf, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, google-maps, browser

does anyone know whats is going on with google maps lately? when i do a request to maps.google.com sometimes it returns a 404 page but right after when i request the same url it will load correctly. This does not happen always but sometimes the 404 page shows. My application is WPF based with vb and im using a webbrowser to display a route from point A to point B. Like i said sometimes when i press the button to display the google maps i get the 404 page but the same route will work right after when i try again.

If anyone has any info about this i will be very appreciated, since i can't find anything on the internet.

Regards,

Comment: We may be able to answer programming-questions, so when you assume that there is a problem with your code you should post code. When you think there is a problem with the availability of google-services you must ask google(e.g. via the [**issue-tracker**](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/))

Comment: I'm seeing the same problem with the Google geocode API - just started happening w/o code changes to code that has been working fine.

Comment: @rheitzman ok, looks like its not only me, and yes i also had no changes on the code that was working just fine until a few days ago!